# How to redirect http to https in nginx/1.18.0 ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, https

I want to redirect my domain http://example.com to https://example.com

Anybody can please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance-----------:)

```
server {
    listen 85;
    listen [::]:85;
    server_name example.com;
    return 302 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 85 ;
    listen [::]:85 ;
    

    server_name example.com www.example.com; # managed by Certbot

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/shoaib/dir/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /home/shoaib/dir/media_root/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/car.sock;
    }
    

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}
```

Answer (score 0):

i do something like this :

```
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

301 is for permanent redirection

Comment: this is not working my domain is showing "Welcome to nginx!"

Answer (score 0):

```
I use this config

server {
    listen 80;
    listen myIP:443;
    server_name www.exemple.fr exemple.fr;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server{

   
    listen               80;
    listen               443 ssl ;
    server_name          exemple.fr;
    
    

    return 301 https://www.exemple.fr$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> this is not working my domain is showing "Welcome to nginx!"

Try rebooting your nginx using superuser and try again:

```
service nginx restart
```

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/nginx-start-stop-restart#htoc-force-restart-nginx

> For major configuration changes, you can force a full restart of
> Nginx. This force-closes the whole service and sub-processes, and
> restarts the whole package.